# How to save configuration file/delete server

Tags: phpmyadmin

Does anybody know why the save button disappeared and how to fix it? [image]

Also I can't delete or edit servers, I'm getting an error:

```
The requested URL /~ME/phpmyadmin/setup/&page=servers&mode=remove&id=1 was not found on this server.
```

I'm using MacOS 10.12

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin 4.7.0  https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/
  Released 2017-03-29
It's a bug,phpmyadmin save script doesn't work in v. 4.7.0, old versions work normally.